# 【Python】Calling async function with another function in different class?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a Class with an asynchronous function:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

class CLASSa():
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.voice_states = {}
    
    @commands.command(name='cmd', invoke_without_subcommand=True)
    async def _cmd(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        """Omit"""
```

I want to call this function `_cmd` externally. The current code I wrote and structure is like this:

```py
def function(bot, ctx):
    """!!!CALL_cmd!!!"""
    obj = CLASSA(bot)
    obj.bot.loop.create_task(obj._cmd(obj,ctx))

class CLASSb():
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, ctx):
        function(self.bot, ctx)
```

error:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-15' coro=<Command.__call__() done, defined at /opt/virtualenvs/python3/project_name/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py:358> exception=TypeError("_cmd() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/project_name/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 374, in __call__
    return await self.callback(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: _cmd() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is btw a typo `CASSa` ...

Comment: Has been update.But the problem isn't here.

Comment: it's possible the discord commands.command wrapper is not handling class member functions well,im saying this because i assume if you don't put that function inside a class it works as intended, you can test if that's the case by not declaring the ctx parameter in your function and then printing `type(self)` if it says it's a commands.Context object it means the wrapper doesn't allow for class functions calls and you either need to rework your code to handle that or edit the commands.command wrapper

Comment: Indeed.thanks for your help <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `@command` decorator is changing the signature of your function.

You may want to refactor the core functionality out and only call that bare function:

```
from discord.ext import commands

class CLASSA():
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.voice_states = {}
    
    async def core_functionality(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        """Omit"""

    @commands.command(name='cmd', invoke_without_subcommand=True):
    async def _cmd(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        return self.core_functionality(ctx)

def function(bot, ctx):
    """!!!CALL_cmd!!!"""
    obj.bot.loop.create_task(CLASSA(bot).core_functionality(ctx))
```

Comment: It turned out that the problem was here. Use another bare function to mobilize the command.
Finally! But then I ran into a problem that I couldn't understand at all.lol